# How to check if a string is included in the type

Tags: typescript

for example(deno)

```js
type Status = 'new' | 'update' | 'close';
itemRequest(status: Status) {...};

let userAnswer = prompt('status:');
if(/*if answer is included in Status*/){
  itemRequest(userAnswer);
}
```

How to check if a string is included in the type?
I don't want to use an array if I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot address a type like `Status` at the value level. However, you can do the following:

```
const statuses = ['new', 'update', 'close'] as const;
type Status = typeof statuses[number]; // enumerates the values in the array as type
...
```

and then in the callback:

```
if ((statuses as readonly string[]).includes(answer)) { // Edit: Added as readonly string[]
  userAnswser = answer;
  rl.close();
}
```

Another possibility would be to use an `enum`, which exists at both type and value level. I would prefer the array way though.

Comment: There is an error indication in the ide:
```Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type "'new' | 'update' | 'close'".```.   
Is this error indication error?

Comment: Oh sorry, I always forget that... `statuses` is of type `('new' | 'update' | 'close')[]` then, so that you have to cast it to `string[]` before testing. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Should work... Which error occurs?